# How to test Exception in signal?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a signal:

```
create_flat_referral = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=["request", "user"])
```

And I have a receiver:

```
@receiver(create_flat_referral, sender=None)
def save_flat_referral(sender, request, user, **kwargs):

    referral_link = request.POST.get('referral', None)
    if not referral_link:
        referral_link = request.GET.get('ref', None)

    try:
        if referral_link:
            link = Link.objects.get(token = referral_link)
            referral = FlatReferral.objects.create(
                referrer = link.user,
                referred = user
            )
    except Link.DoesNotExist:
        logger.exception('...')
    except ValidationError:
        logger.exception('...')
```

I want to cover all the exceptions with the tests.

[image]

In addition to what I want to get `assertRaises`, I also want to get `assertRaisesMessage`

What's the best way to do this?

If I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    self.assertRaises(
        ValidationError,
        lambda: signals.create_flat_referral.send(
            sender = None,
            request = post_request,
            user = self.referred
        )
    )
```

That I fail the test:

> AssertionError: ValidationError not raised by lambda

Answer (score -1):

> AssertionError: ValidationError not raised by lambda

The definition where callable is a func name, not a func() call

```
`assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)`
```

e.g, this will work as `cal_exp` is func name

```
 self.assertRaises(OverflowError, MathOverFlow().cal_exp, 2)
```

This will not work, as `cal_exp(2)` is not valid for assert

```
 self.assertRaises(OverflowError, MathOverFlow().cal_exp(2))
```

I personally prefer this way:

```
d = {'sender': None, 'request': post_request, 'user': self.referred}

with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
    signals.create_flat_referral.send(**d)
```

OR a func name with `**kwargs`, not `func(**kwargs)`

```
self.assertRaises(ValidationError, signals.create_flat_referral.send, **d)
```

I cannot find a place for `lamda`, or at least it made things more complicated than necessary here.

Answer (score -1):

You need to test your signal handler itself - not Django's signal framework (which is thoroughly tested by Django itself). So you don't need to go through all the trouble of triggering an actual signal - you can just call your function directly with simulated parameters, and check that it handles them correctly - something like this:

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

class MySignalTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_link_does_not_exist(self):
        # Create a dummy request that you can give to your signal handler
        factory = RequestFactory()
        request = factory.post('/')   # Pass appropriate params here if needed

       with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
           # sender isn't used, hence you can just pass None there.
           save_flat_referral(sender=None, request=request)
```